# Cordova - app crashes on both iOS/Android after an OS upgrade

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

This is an issue that's affected a hybrid app built using Sencha Touch and another hybrid app built using Ionic.  Both apps are packaged using the latest version of Cordova to generate the iOS and Android binaries.

I install the app on a device running, say Android 5.1.1.  Open the app, it works fine.  Then I upgrade the device to Android 6.0.  Open that app and it freezes/crashes.  Only solution to this problem is to uninstall the app and re-install on Android 6.0, which is a major inconvenience for the user.

Anyone else experience this same issue?  I Googled but got nothing in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade your application with the help of latest cordova pack with existing playstore key generated for your existing app. Try it may work but not sure.